# Java matching different arrays

Tags: java

So I am trying to take basic input values like `a` or `b` between two different user inputs, match them, and print the score for that one loop, then also print the accumulative total score. I feel like I am doing it right but every time my score prints out the value of 0. So lets say the key values are `a a a` and the and values are `a b a`. That should print out the value 2, and continually run, also resetting the score back to 0.

```
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(reader);
    BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String inputValue;
    String[] key;
    String[] ans;
    int totalScore = 0;

    inputValue = input1.readLine();
    key = inputValue.split("\\s+");

    while(true){

       int score = 0;

       inputValue = input2.readLine();
       ans = inputValue.split("\\s+");

       if(key[0] == ans[0])
          score += 1;
       if(key[1] == ans[1])
          score += 1;
       if(key[2] == ans[2])
          score += 1;

       totalScore = score;

       System.out.print(score + "\n");
       System.out.print(totalScore + "\n");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings; use `.equals()` instead of `==`

example:

```
if (key[0].equals(ans[0])) {}
```

Remember: (almost) **Always** use `.equals()` for string comparison.

Comment: thanks I though that it should have been ==

Comment: what it I want to check and see `if(key[0].equals("a") || key[0].equals("A"))` to catch uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: .equalsIgnoreCase("a") will catch both A and a